# Custom bootstrap styles without `WARNING: You probably don't mean to use the color value blue in interpolation here.`

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

I've been following this guide (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#importing) to import bootstrap's styles for further modification.

```
// Custom.scss
// Option B: Include parts of Bootstrap

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// 4. Include any optional Bootstrap components as you like
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";

// 5. Add additional custom code here
```

However, when building the application, the following warning is shown.

```
WARNING: You probably don't mean to use the color value blue in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as blue, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings or map keys (for example, "blue").
If you really want to use the color value here, use '"" + $color'.


9      --#{$variable-prefix}#{$color}: #{$value};
^^^^^^

node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_root.scss 9:28  @import
src/assets/styles/custom.scss 19:9              root stylesheet
```

Line 19 points to `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";`

I've tried to resolve this, but haven't been able to do so yet. What I've done is to reference `custom.scss` everywhere in the application code, instead of `bootstrap.scss`.

Has anyone come across this warning and how can the root source of this warning be resolved and what does it mean if it is ignored (the application seems to show the appropriate styles just fine - however I have a suspicion that the bundled css might contain duplicates, as it's rather large)?

Comment: Update your versions of bootstrap & sass.

Comment: @isherwood - it's Bootstrap 5.1.3 to be more precise (not 5.0.0).

Comment: Well, you linked to an inappropriate docs page then, which is confusing. Rather than telling us down here, maybe fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake when I started to make some color definition for my project. Something like this:

```
$colors: (
    stone: (
        100: hsl(210, 40%, 96%),
        200: hsl(214, 32%, 91%),
        300: hsl(213, 27%, 84%),
        400: hsl(215, 20%, 65%),
        500: hsl(215, 16%, 47%),
    ),
    gray: (
        100: hsl(220, 14%, 96%),
        200: hsl(220, 13%, 91%),
        300: hsl(216, 12%, 84%),
        400: hsl(218, 11%, 65%),
        500: hsl(220, 9%, 46%),
    )...
```

After that I tried to interpolate over this.

```
@use './abstracts' as vars;

.#{vars.$prefix} {
    @each $color, $shades in vars.$colors {
        @each $prop, $value in $shades {
            --#{vars.$prefix}color-#{$color}-#{$prop}: #{$value};
        }
    }
}
```

Since this is a nested array, nested @each are also necessary. And this is where the error occurs. SASS in the current version tries to avoid a redefinition of colors without recognizing that the color name is only a part of the whole name.

The solution is to store the composite name in an intermediate variable and then use that.

```
@use './abstracts' as vars;

.#{vars.$prefix} {
    @each $color, $shades in vars.$colors {
        @each $prop, $value in $shades {
            $property: #{vars.$prefix}color-#{$color}-#{$prop};
            --#{$property}: #{$value};
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is not a direct solution to your problem, since you have your definition from the bootstrap sources. You had to open an issue in the bootstrap repo for it, or fix the bug yourself and create a PR.
But I hope it helps others who get such a problem.